# Hadoop: Sorting and shuffling

Tags: hadoop

I'am new to hadoop area. Can you please help me whose responsibility it is to get us the output in the form of (`k2,list[v2,v2,v2...]`) (meaning combining key with all it's associated values)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how the MapReduce component of Hadoop works, find the maximum air temperature of Egypt per year.

given a set of temperature value per year records

```
sample record1: 1995, Jan, Cairo , 33, C
sample record2: 1995, Feb, Cairo , 37, C
......
......
```

The map function parses the input records by extracting the year and the air temperature, and emits them as its output

```
example map output
(1950,0)
(1950, 22)
(1950, -11)
(1949, 111)
(1949, 78)
```

Then, the output from the map function is processed by the MapReduce framework **before** being sent to the reduce function. This processing sorts and groups the key-value pairs by key

```
sample sort output 
(1949, [111, 78])
(1950, [0, 22, −11])
```

Finally, each year appears with a list of all its air temperature readings. All the reduce function has to do now is iterate through the list and pick up the maximum reading:

```
(1949, 111)
(1950, 22)
```

Refernce: [Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, 4th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033448.do)

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Thanks a lot for the above information. So if i understand it correctly, sample sort output (1949,[111,78]) is written to the disk. This data will be sent to the reducer function. Can you also please help me to understand how grouping of the keys takes place (meaning what class is responsible for this operation).

Comment: The reduce function aggregates the values associated with each key in this example ( year ), so you have a reduce task instantiated for each key. Values associated with each key are automatically sorted and grouped by Hadoop before they are presented to the Reducer. As a programmer, all what you have to do is writing the map and reduce logic.

Comment: Appreciate your brisk response on this Ahmed. You mentioned  that Values associated with each key are automatically sorted and grouped by Hadoop before they are presented to the Reducer. But, what i think is keys are sorted and grouped by hadoop before they are presented to the reducer (Please Correct me if i am wrong). What i need to know is for instance, hadoop uses quick sort algorithm to sort the keys But what is used to group the keys. Thanks in advance.